# Are two different definitions for Čech cohomology equivalent?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, cohomology, cech-cohomology

In Spanier's book Algebraic Topology (Chapter 6 section 7) he defines Čech cohomology in terms of the nerves of open coverings.
I wish to know if this is equivalent, for a topological space A closed in X, to the direct limit of singular cohomologies of open sets in X containing A.

In particular, I am interested in the case where we have a constant coefficient group (rather than a presheaf) but for any topological space X (not necessarily Hausdorff or compact, etc.).

NOTE:
I have reason to believe that they are not.
In "Foundations of Algebra" (Eilenberg, Steenrod 1952), I believe that they define Čech cohomology in terms of nerves of open coverings, the same way that Spanier does.
However, for this definition of Čech cohomology they show that the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms hold, while the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms don't necessarily hold for the alternative definition of Čech cohomology that I have described.
Any clarifications or input welcome

EDIT:
the second definition of Čech cohomology I've referenced is the one defined in Miller's "Lectures on Algebraic Topology" chapter 35 and is $\check{H}^n(A) := \varinjlim_{U \in \mathcal{U}_A} H^n(U)$
where $\mathcal{U}_A$ is the directed set whose elements are the open subsets of a topological space $X$ containing $A \subseteq X$ ordered such that $U \leq V$ when $V \subseteq U$

Comment: Could you explain your definition? Are you describing $H^*(X,A)$?

Comment: When $A=X$ or more generally, when $A$ is clopen (closed and open) in $X$ then this direct limit is just anything, depending on the "original" cohomology in $X.$

Comment: @abx I've written more on the second definition. Hopefully that is the one you wanted clarification on?

Comment: @WlodAA if $A$ is clopen then I believe the Čech cohomology would be isomorphic to the singular cohomology. I'm not sure why this is relevant though.

Comment: Right, if the ORIGINAL theory was singular then we get the singular theory back (and not the Cech theory).

Comment: Yes, this is what I was asking for. But I think @Wlod AA is right: if $A=X$, you get the singular cohomology, which is not always isomorphic to the Čech cohomology.

Answer (score 6):

If $X$ is a closed subset of a manifold $M$, then the Cech cohomology of $X$ coincides with the direct limit of the singular cohomology of $U$ over open sets containing $X$. This becomes useful in discussing Poincare duality: one finds that (under compactness and orientation assumptions) $H_p(X,A)$ is isomorphic to the $(n-p)th$ Cech cohomology of $A$. But it is unfortunate to refer to this direct limit as a *definition* of Cech cohomology.

It seems that Miller is taking a short cut that has misled you; instead of giving the correct definition of Cech cohomology and stating that in this case it is isomorphic to that direct limit, he is simply referring to the direct limit as Cech cohomology.

(In a way, this is understandable. He has no need to say anything about the theory of Cech cohomology in order to prove theorems about duality in manifolds.)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of Čech cohomology lends itself to a full sheaf cohomology theory over any fixed space or pair. When you have a sheaf cohomology you can test it against Grothendieck's axioms (as in his Tohoku paper from 1957). Singular cohomology leads to a sheaf cohomology generalization only for spaces and pairs that satisfy some additional condition, for example you may need local contractibility. It is for this restricted class of spaces that you can establish an isomorphism between the singular and Čech theories.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't think that it is relevant. I'm wondering about two different Čech theories not singular cohomology.

Comment: You mention the definition of Čech cohomology in terms of nerves of coverings. What is the second definition of Čech cohomology that you want to compare this with?

Comment: It is described in the edit

Comment: @JoelSpringer It's not clear what $H^n(U)$ means in the edit: note that singular cohomology satisfies the Eilenberg--Steenrod axioms so if $H^n(U)$ denotes singular cohomology of $U$ then you get singular cohomology, instead of an alternative approach to Čech cohomology.

Comment: I think that it is quite clear. It is the direct limit of singular cohomologies

Answer (score 0):

Let $\ X\ $ be a (Hilbert) cube of arbitrary dimension (finite or infinite -- of arbitrary cardinal number). Then the two cohomology theories of arbitrary closed subset $\ A\subseteq X\ $ (considered by OP) are canonically isomorphic.

Comment: "canonical" in the terms of the natural transformation isomorphism.